# Preventing users to login again after closing the app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem in my login page. after successful login my account, and close the app and re-open it, The screen is still on the login page. How can I make my app like Facebook? I have tried to implement `SharedPreferences` but I'm passing an `IntentExtra` every time the user has successfully logged in.

Thanks

**EDIT: add screenshot of code**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a shared preference class like this:-

```
    public class AppPrefrences {

            private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
            private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

            public static boolean isUserLoggedOut(Context ctx) {
                mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                return mPrefs.getBoolean("id_logged_in", true);
            }

            public static void setUserLoggedOut(Context ctx, Boolean value) {
                mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mPrefsEditor.putBoolean("id_logged_in", value);
                mPrefsEditor.commit();
            }

    public static String getUserName(Context ctx) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            return mPrefs.getString("userName", "");
        }

        public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String value) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            mPrefsEditor.putString("userName", value);
            mPrefsEditor.commit();
        }

public static void clearAllPreferences(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.clear();
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
        }
```

and when you login in your app then set the value like this:-

```
setUserLoggedOut(YourActivity.class, false);
```

and set a check on splash screen like this:-

```
if (isUserLoggedOut(StartActivity.this)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. where will be the username and password will be saved?

Comment: @MikeGorospe Store user object in shared preference. No need to store password

Comment: your can create your own getter an setter in this class

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. I add an screenshot of code which if the API response successfully

Comment: this is the best practice to create a session in your app

Comment: Hi. it's working now, but the problem is, the data I need is gone. which is the `intent.putExtra` on the screenshot

Comment: what do you want to do ? explain

Comment: I need the data on the `intent` for the mainpage

Comment: save your data in shared preference and get where you want this data using the same shared preference object

Comment: @SandeepMalik it's working now :). sorry, first timer on getter and setter stuff :). thank you so much for making me understand it more clearer.

Comment: @SandeepMalik one last thing. how can I clear the existing `SharedPreferences`

Comment: i have updated my answer look at there clear method is added in the answer