# How can i store user login data in app data in webview based application?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have created an app with WebView in android studio. The website which i have linked in WebView basically required login first. So whenever user successfully login in the website through my app after some hours it requires login again.

So I want that whenever user login so the app should store user's login details (ID and Password) and don't logout automatically until the user logout himself.

Comment: You can use Shared Preference to store user info

Comment: @RajendraMahato You should NEVER EVER use SharedPreferences to store sensitive information.

Comment: @Slobodan but we can store tokens, right?

Comment: @RajendraMahato No, we should not. You should use [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) for storing any kind of login info.

Comment: you should try this answer to save user details :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644253/preventing-users-to-login-again-after-closing-the-app/55644272#55644272

Comment: Please read carefully above description,My application is WebView based so we can't use shared Preference in WebView, because user is login actually in a website not in app.