# Login using Json with shared Preferences

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

Login using JSON with shared Preferences   When user Enter their Phone Number then user got success from API and go to new activity and after resume app, users state will log in 
        When user Enter their Phone Number then user got success from API and go to new activity and after resume app, users state will log in

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    usr_number = findViewById(R.id.usr_pass);

    go = findViewById(R.id.button);
    signup = findViewById(R.id.signup_signup);

    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getjsondata();

            String hhh = usr_number.getText().toString();
            url = "http://readnow.flatdeal4u.com/Api/Register.aspx?mobile=" + hhh + "&choice=2";
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+hhh, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (usr_number.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                usr_number.setError("Enter Phone Number");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (usr_number.getText().toString().equals("" + hhh)) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, select_your_exams.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    pref = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                    pref.getString("mobilenumber", hhh);
                    pref.getString("nameofuser", "");
                }
            }

        }
    });


    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**Here are my JSON method codes:**

```
public void get JSON data) {
    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener < String > () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = jobj.getJSONArray("userInfos");

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data found"+array, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    final Phn_modal mo = new Phn_modal();

                    final String mobile = obj.getString("mobileNumber");
                    final String name = obj.getString("fullName");
                    final String email = obj.getString("emailId");

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome You-" + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mo.setMobile(mobile);
                    mo.setName(name);
                    mo.setEmailId(email);

                    mo.getMobile(mobile);
                    mo.getMobile(name);

                    editor.putString("mobilenumber", mobile);
                    editor.putString("nameofuser", name);

                    editor.apply();
                    editor.commit();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: And what's your question? Is there anything not working with all that code? If yes, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i think your question is , you login first time, and next time you again visit application that time directly go to the activity withouth asking login,

then you can try this.

```
 public void storeString(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

above function is used to store the specific value in our shared prefrence, with given key.

Now when we hint the login button that time if login is success then store the login success value in our prefrence.
this one is usefull for again visit in your application

```
storeString(mPreferences, "Login_flag", "true");
```

-> Now, when we again visit application check the our prefrence is true or false.
if our prefrence is true then user already login, not required to login again
Check like this,

```
if(mPreferences.getString(PreferenceList.LOGIN_FLAG, "false").equals("true")){
 //if alredy login then access this
}else{
 //if not login then access this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a login session in your app then you should create an preference class in your project and save data in that class and match the data where you want to use follow this answer to maintain the login session in your app:- [Preventing users to login again after closing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644253/preventing-users-to-login-again-after-closing-the-app/55644272#55644272)