# How can I store values from an activity so that I can use them later?

Tags: android

I would like to store a few values from an Activity so that when I navigate away from the activity, they still appear there.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        Button AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText firstNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNumEditText);
                EditText secondNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumEditText);
                TextView ResultTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultTxtView);

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumEditText.getText().toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumEditText.getText().toString());
                int result = num1 + num2;
                ResultTxtView.setText(result + "");

            }
        });
```

In this case, I only want to save the values of `num1`, `num2` and `result`.  I would like it so that if I navigate back to the main menu, or if I go and do some other app and come back tomorrow, that the values would still be there.

Comment: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) is what you need.

Comment: you can follow this answer to save and retrieve data from shared preference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644253/preventing-users-to-login-again-after-closing-the-app/55644272#55644272

Answer (score 1):

You can store these values by using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        Button AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText firstNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNumEditText);
                EditText secondNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumEditText);
                TextView ResultTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultTxtView);

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumEditText.getText().toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumEditText.getText().toString());
                int result = num1 + num2;
                ResultTxtView.setText(result + "");
                // You can store these values here
                // ...
            }
        });

protected void onResume() {
    // And read these values here and set to your ResultTxtView.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preferences in your app for saving the data and for using the same data later as mentioned below:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("Name", "Alex");
        editor.putString("Email", "alex@gmail.com");
        editor.commit();
```

And then if you want to get the same data in another activity you do this as mentioned below:

```
SharedPreferences sp= ActvivityA.this.getSharedPreferences("Data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = sp.getString("Name");
String email = sp.getString("Email");
```

This data will be saved till you will not clear the cache of the application or you will not install a new update of the app so in this way you can use this data anywhere in the app.

Comment: What if I want to use it in the same activity?  Let's say I want to go to another activity in the app, "ActivityB" , but I want it to still be there when I come back to "ActivityA"

Comment: You can use that in the same activity but after saving the data you have to make sure that you have saved the data in the shared preferences else when you will get the data then you will receive the null or " " values

Answer (score 1):

*In this case, I only want to save the values of num1, num2 and result. I would like it so that if I navigate back to the main menu, or if I go and do some other app and come back **tomorrow**, that the values would still be there.*

When you need the values to be persisted across app launches, then Shared Preferences or a data store like SQLite/Room would be the way to go.

**Shared Preferences** : If the values stored are key value pairs and are limited in size and does not have to scale, then Shared Preference would suit your need.

**SqLite** : If the data that you store would scale and would become larger in time, then you need to look at a data store like SQLite where you can do Async operations.

Comment: Ultimately, I think I will only have to store a few values, which would be four doubles.  I think that Shared Preferences should work.

Answer (score 0):

create on class which extends Application and create variable to hold specific value and register that class in manifest
in manifest in application tag specify your application class name

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private MyApplication sInstance;
int result;
//write getter setter for result variable same for num1 and num2
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
}
public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}
}
```

in onClick set that variable value like `MyApplication.getInstnce().setResult();`
and in onCreate of set textview value with MyApplication.getInstance().getResult();

Answer (score 0):

Use Following methods for save/retrieve string using SharedPreferences

```
 public static int getIntPreferences(Context context,String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    int savedPref = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, null);
    return savedPref;
}

public static void saveIntPreferences(Context context,String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Save num1,num2 and result using saveIntPreferences when you leave 1st Activity.

After getting back on 1st Activity, you can get saved value using getIntPreferences