# How can i save the state of the Button to shared preferences?

Tags: java, android

This is my code of adapter where I want to store the button is enabled or disabled to shared preference. I have four bottom navigation in this project and each time I navigate to this Fragment, the state of button gets refreshed. To prevent this from happening, I think it's better option to save to Shared Preference that the button is enabled or disabled.

Here is the code of the data adapter where setOnClickListeners of buttons are located.

```
package com.example.projectrefill;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.ColorSpace;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class adapter_clientside_order_list extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<client_model_home_orders,adapter_clientside_order_list.myviewholder> implements Filterable
        {


            public adapter_clientside_order_list(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<client_model_home_orders> options) {
                super(options);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull client_model_home_orders model) {
                holder.textView.setText(model.getName());
                holder.btnchk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity=(AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                        appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.wrapper,new Checkordersbtn_client_Fragment(model.getName())).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    }
                });


                holder.btnacp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "accepting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String retailername,itemname,quan;

                        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();


                        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                        String formattedDate = df.format(c).toString();
                        System.out.println("date to display for the system   "+formattedDate);

                        holder.btndel.setEnabled(true);
                        holder.btnacp.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.btncan.setEnabled(false);

                      


                    }
                });


                holder.btncan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "cancelling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        holder.btncan.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.btnacp.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.btndel.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                });



                holder.btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        holder.btndel.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.btnacp.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.btncan.setEnabled(false);
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
               View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row_order_clientside_homepage,parent,false);
               return new myviewholder(view);
            }


            @Override
            public Filter getFilter() {
                return null;
            }


            public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
             {
                    Button btnchk,btnacp,btncan,btndel;
                    TextView textView;


        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.retailer_name);
            btnchk=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_checkorders);
            btnacp=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_accept);
            btncan=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancl);
            btndel=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_deli);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287319/how-to-save-button-state-in-shared-preference

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first step is to write a getter setter method inside your pref manager class.

```
public String BUTTON_STATE= "KEY_BUTTONSTATE";

    public void setbuttonstate(boolean state) {
            editor.putBoolean(BUTTON_STATE, state);
            editor.commit();
        }
    
        public boolean getbuttonstate() {
            return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(BUTTON_STATE, false);
        }
```

Now your getter should return a boolean value on which you will verify the last state of your button, by default it will be false

Now first intialize your pref manager class inside adapter and after that inside your  `holder.btnacp` click listener do this:

```
yourprefmanagerclassname.setbuttonstate(true)
```

What this means is that when the button is clicked it is set checked to true and the above line will save it's state to the method written in your prefmanager

Now for the final step add this line in start of adapter:

```
if ( yourprefmanagerclassname.getbuttonstate) {
            btnacp.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Whenever your adapter will be initialised, this above method will check it's last state and set it accordingly, don't forget to add null checks for pref manager class and then for methods !!

Do let me know if this helps you !!

Comment: That was helpful but can you guide me in creating preference manager class and adding set and get method to itt?

Comment: I was not able to access the method setbuttonstate from the adapter.

Comment: it is as easy as you make another class just create a new class and name it prefsmanager, declare a string key as i mentioned above and if you're on android studio click alt + enter and select getter setter it will generate automatically