# How can i get current user information by single declaration?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have many activities and also it has many methods in my app and every activity needs current user information like fristname, lastname, username from firebase database. For this, I have to declare variable every time by below codes.

```
 UserRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        String myProfileImage=dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                        String userfirstname=dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue().toString();
                        String userlastname=dataSnapshot.child("lastname").getValue().toString();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
        });
```

So, now the question is, Is there any way to declare these three variable in globally and it can be use in any activity ?

Comment: You can store them in SharedPreferences but you would need to do some work to make sure the data is updated when the user signs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:**

Although the approach I am about to suggest works, it is a crude approach. To tackle this problem the proper way (using FirebaseUser), look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56843921/5670752).

---

You can solve this problem by using SharedPreferences. In a nutshell, when a user signs up, you save his detail into a temporary storage called SharedPreferences. Every time you need it, you can simply retrieve it with minimal lines of code.

To save user details into SharedPreferences, you can use the method below:

```
public void saveToSharedPreferences(String firstName, String lastName, String photoUrl) {

    // declare your sharedpreferences and editor variables
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    // save your values
    editor.putString("firstName", firstName);
    editor.putString("lastName", lastName);
    editor.putString("photoUrl", photoUrl);

    // commit your changes
    editor.apply();

}
```

To retrieve your values, use these lines of code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("USER", MODE_PRIVATE);

String firstName = sharedPreferences.getString("firstName", "not found");
String lastName = sharedPreferences.getString("lastName", "not found");
String photoUrl = sharedPreferences.getString("photoUrl", "not found");
```

> Note that **"not found"** represents your placeholder String just in
>   case there is no data to retrieve.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: if i am not wrong, this similar things of  Intent, Intent pass data between two corresponding activities and SharedPreferences  share data (String, int, long)throughout the app

Comment: Yeah! Exactly!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current Firebase user using like this:

```java
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FirebaseUser class to solve your problem. It has awesome functions you can use to store user profile data.

When a user logs in or signs up, get all the details you need (firstName, lastName photoUrl) from FirebaseDatabase. After getting these values, pass them into the method below:

```
public void saveUserData(String firstName, String lastName, String photoUrl) {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
    .setDisplayName(firstName + " "+lastName)
    .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(photoUrl))
    .build();

    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
      .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated..");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, anytime you want to retrieve the user's profile, do this:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        String firstName = profile.getDisplayName().split(" ")[0];
        String lastName = profile.getDisplayName().split(" ")[1];
        Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: is there any options for static global variable like, suppose i make one public class and in which i defined string variable from firebase logged user, and it can be used in any activity  or class file ?

Comment: For that, you can use SharedPreferences.

Comment: Now its a main question how to do this , whats this?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to store the logged in user information in Shared Preference. You can create an AppPreference Class and set getter and setter according to your need. I am referring an answer to set and get useful information to follow this link :- [Preventing users to login again after closing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644253/preventing-users-to-login-again-after-closing-the-app/55644272#55644272)